# After Validation from database, how to go to another activity in android

Tags: android

I am Creating an app where i login into app,it matches the data with database and then permits the user to login. But every time i press on login and go to another activity , the application terminates

```
public void userlogin(View view){

    logname = et1.getText().toString();//retrieving details from Username field
    logpass = et2.getText().toString();//retrieving details from Password field

    String method = "Login";
    BackTask bt = new BackTask(this);
    bt.execute(method,logname,logpass);//checking from database 
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();//session management

    editor.putString(Name, logname);
    editor.putString(Pass, logpass);
    if(editor.commit())
    {
    Intent in = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Create.class);
    startActivity(in);
    }
    //starting another activty 
}
```

Comment: Have you registered "Create" activity in Manifest file? Also there are many possible reason for app termination Please check logcat for possible error.

Comment: is the application crashing?  or just disappearing?

Comment: What is the exception in the logcat when the app crashes?

Comment: it is showing -fatal exception, IIlegalStackException